# Synonyms for "old" with positive connotations (and some conditions)

Tags: synonyms

I want to describe a project for categorizing 'old' things, as well as antedating things that may not be very old*. I'm looking for a word to describe their age.

First, I would like a positive or at least neutral connotation. "Antedate" is good in this sense, "old" not so much. (But I don't want to restrict the scope to just things that are known at the present but for which older uses are found, but also to include categorizing existing old things and discovering previously-unknown old things.)

Second, the term should not imply great antiquity. The things under consideration are a type of mathematical object and most will be fairly recent (19th or 20th century), though a few will be older.

Finally the term should not be overly obscure. Perhaps there is a common word which I have overlooked; if not, at least it should be a word with some currency.

At the moment I'm leaning toward "historical" which is not great but may suffice.  Can you find a better word?

* That is, for something known to date back to N, find a use of it from year M where M < N. "Fibonacci's identity was actually first studied by Diophantus 900 years earlier."

Comment: Could you help us out with a sentence or phrase using "old" so we can replace that with the appropriate word? As in "He traveled on the 'old' 20th-century limited" a 20th century object but not a mathematical one, alas.

Comment: @robrambusch: I gave three sentences in the comments below.  But in the end I'm not using it in a sentence but as the name of a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, maybe a phrase, such as *well-studied* would be good. It implies that the mathematical objects have been known for a while, but does not have any negative connotations (to me), nor implies great antiquity. I think it depends a lot on the context. Had you asked for a similar word to describe cheese, I'd have suggested *aged* or *well aged*, but I don't think that applies at all in this case. ;)

---

I re-wrote one of your sentences to not use the word "old". In the other two contexts, I honestly don't see anything wrong with it.

> The Foo sequence is named after John Foo, but it is actually *the same sequence as earlier 
>   discovered* by Amy Bar in 1945.

Comment: That's really good, but actually my focus is the opposite -- finding things that perhaps have been almost lost to the ages and recording them.  Hmm... I should make that more clear in my question.  In any case, +1.

Comment: @Charles: Hmm that's a little trickier - do you have a sample sentence you'd like to use this phrase in?

Comment: Well I'm looking to use it as the name of a project more than in sentences alone, but for the purpose of context: "The Fibonacci numbers are an (old) sequence." / "The Foo sequence is named after John Foo, but is actually an (old) sequence discovered by Amy Bar in 1945." / "A reference to a previously unknown (old) sequence studied in 1540 was uncovered last year."

Comment: @Charles: Updates. I don't see anything really that wrong with the word "old" in these contexts. I think it fits just fine, and don't see any negative connotations to its use here.

Comment: Perhaps, in those sentences. But I'm looking for an umbrella term that covers all three. One problem with the word, as in my original question, is that many of the things referred to are not actually old (just older than most of the rest).

Comment: @Charles: I don't think that's a serious problem here. The word "old" is usually understood to be a relative term. You could use the words "older" or "earlier" if you want to make this more obvious.

Answer (score 5):

You may refer to the objects as *classical*.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be entirely appropriate as the OP does specify that the term should not imply "great antiquity". On the other hand, "classical" can mean "of or relating to a form or system considered of first significance in earlier times" (source: Merriam-Webster). This definition could or could not be applicable to the OP's mathematical objects.

Comment: Unfortunately some of the things of interest will be from, say, the 1970s and 1980s, so not nearly "classical".  It meets the other criteria pretty well, though.

Comment: @JasperLoy: I would not describe things from the 1980s as "old" -- that's why I'm looking for a different word. There's good reason to distinguish modern computers, say, from those from the 80s, even though it's not that long ago in some sense.  There a word like "vintage" or "retro" or "legacy" would be appropriate; here it is not, because the math doesn't age as technology does.  But I'd like a term that fits so I came here for help.  As for the use of the word in mathematics, that is another reason to avoid it--I wouldn't want to suggest things related to classical analysis when I mean old.

Answer (score 2):

The word we use in the computer industry is **legacy**. It can have the positive connotation of a bequest from past masters. Or, it can have the negative connotation of a sort of white elephant that one must take care of even though it is obsolete. The connotation is usually clear from context.

Answer (score 2):

Does *vintage* fit the objects in question in the way you want?

Answer (score 0):

A positive word that implies age is **venerable**.  Something that is venerable deserves respect.  Further, we usually use this word to describe someone or something that is still alive, which suits your requirement that it not suggest antiquity.

Comment: Yes, this would be good were I describing people.

Answer (score 0):

From the latin prefix *ante-* ("before"), we have **antique**. This word perfectly describes something that is older, and often comes with positive connotations.

Comment: It does have a nice connotation, but I need something that doesn't suggest such age since most of what I'm working with isn't really even all that old (20th century).  They are, of their class, relatively old but not very old on an absolute scale.

Comment: In that case "vintage" (see Kevin's answer) might be the better choice. A *vintage computer* makes sense in such a context. However, if it's clear that it's something that doesn't go back for centuries, an *antique computer* would make sense too. However, an *antique vase* could be much older...

Comment: Vintage is not appropriate here as the mathematical constructs do not age.

Comment: (Sorry to be difficult! It's a hard request.)

Answer (score 0):

*Predate* sounds less obscure than *antedate*, to my ear.

(Unfortunately, I don't know how you could form an adjective nicely out of *predate*. It also sounds like "to hunt", as a predator.)

Here are some ideas for adjectives:

- historical
- previous
- established
- known
- accepted
- past
- long-ago
- bygone
- already discovered
- contemporary
- coeval
- circa

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but **traditional** and **conventional** comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using something like *8-bit* ? Not necessarily that specific formulation but something that clearly implies a previous generation of computers.

Comment: No, since I'm not talking about computers.

Comment: Is it possible to tell us what you *are* talking about? Fumbling around in the dark for a "generic" word might not be as efficient as actually knowing what is being described. Unless it's a need-to-know sort of thing in which case we'll continue fumbling. ;-)

Comment: Mathematical sequences like linear recurrence relations, the coefficients of generating functions, prime numbers, and so forth.  Does that help?

Comment: It might - are you classifying old data (flight time of the Hindenburg) or old concepts (20th century Zeppelin design)?

Comment: Neither -- timeless things like the Jacobsthal numbers or the primes.  Some have been 'apparently' discovered recently but I'm antedating them to, say, the 1950s -- these are the "new" things.  Some of them are old (by my standards), say the late 19th century.  Some are literally antiquarian, like the prime numbers, but these represent a small fraction of the whole.

Comment: So the unifying concept is "old, or at least older than you think".

Answer (score 0):

**Ancient** has a positive connotation, and describes exactly what is wanted in the question.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion. Ancient can certainly be used negatively, like ancient horror, ancient nemesis, or ancient terror.